# Remote css background Image not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an external css file where I write following class  something like this 
when I include this class in my Web page
background image not looded even background attribute not include in file .Every thing is work fine but the path of image url is changed it become like

```
http:localhost:1234//http://www.myimg.com/img.jpg
```

How I solve this Issue

```
enter code here
.myclass
{
background:url('http://www.myimg.com/img.jpg');
border: 0 none; 
color: #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
display: block; 
font-weight: bold;
height: 60px;
margin-left: -30px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 265px !important;
}
```

Comment: how have you referenced this external css file?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
background-image:url(http://www.myimg.com/img.jpg);
```

Comment: Can you share the url of your website so that I can see

Comment: This syntax is troubling me. I've always been use to url('') or url(""), not url(). What actually is the only standard way to write this property ?

Comment: There is no need to use quotes. However it will work even when you use with quotes. Check syntax at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have refrenced your external CSS file properly, put this in between your < HEAD > tag:

```
<link href="../FolderName/CSSNAME.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I have Properly added the Reference but I I debug the file in firbug the url would be like this 'http://localhost:1234//http://www.myimage.com'